# How to use VBA to copy a cell and paste into a different cell as values when another cell is changed

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table where column L will be changed by the user. Column M returns a value based on a vlookup off of column L. I am looking for some VBA code that will notice anytime any cell in column L is changed, then copy the result from the Vlookup in column M and paste as values in Column N.

For Example:
User changes/adds value into cell L3
Cell M3 is updated based off of a vlookup using L3
VBA copies the new value in M3
VBA Pastes as values into N3

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Google "excel vba worksheet change event".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   Please refer to the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).   In your case, you need to show what you've tried so far, and why it didn't work.   You can read some Excel tutorial websites for generic information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Worksheet.Change Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) with the [Application.Intersect method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.Intersect) to check if a specific cell was changed.

Use the [Range.Offset property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Offset) to move from the changed cell to another cell where you want to write your value.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range) 
    Dim ChangedCells As Range
    Set ChangedCells = Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("L:L")) 

    Dim Cell As Range

    If Not ChangedCells Is Nothing Then
        'ChangedCells contains all cells that changed and are in column L
        For Each Cell In ChangedCells 'loop through cells
            Cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Value = "aaa" 'offset moves from L to M
        Next Cell
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Very close here. I changed the offset to 2 so it is in the correct column for me. Last piece I need now is instead of the value being "aaa" I need it to copy what is in column M and paste as values into column L

Comment: @BrianHorrell Well, I left some work for you, since you did nothing yet and just watched us working ;)

Comment: You can copy cell values like that: `Cell.Value = Cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=2).Value`

Comment: Final - Thank you!                                                                         
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ChangedCells As Range
    Set ChangedCells = Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("L:L"))

    Dim Cell As Range

    If Not ChangedCells Is Nothing Then
        'ChangedCells contains all cells that changed and are in column L
        For Each Cell In ChangedCells 'loop through cells
            Cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=2).Value = Cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Value 'offset moves from L to M
        Next Cell
    End If